# Improve STS performance

Tags: eclipse, spring, performance, configuration

I've been looking for a way to improve STS performance overall (start-up time, build-time, responsiveness), but the scarce documents I've come across just point me to simple options (usually, already applied).

I wonder if there more advanced settings I can tinker with and possibly a reference/guide/manual to check things out.